# box-shadow assigning pixel values different way compared to padding, margin, border? Not in order top->right->bottom->left

Tags: html, css

Below in code-snippet, in **text1, text2, text3** divs, I am using padding CSS property. As in **padding, margin, border** when we assign pixel values, it's in order top-right-bottom-left OR all 4 sides OR same in "top-bottom" and "right-left" set.

e.g.

`padding: 10px;` => padding from all 4 sides is equals 10px

`padding: 5px 20px;` => padding from top-bottom:5px and right-left:20px

`padding: 5px 10px 15px 20px;` => padding in order of top->right->bottom->left

Then why this order-settings not working in `box-shadow:` property same as above?

```css
.text1
{
  padding: 10px; /*padding from all 4 sides is equals 10px*/
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
.text2
{
  padding: 5px 20px; /*padding from top-bottom:5px and right-left:20px*/
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
.text3
{
  padding: 5px 10px 15px 20px; /*padding in order of top->right->bottom->left*/
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
.myDiv
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
#div1
{
  box-shadow: 5px #888; /*shadow not working on 4 sides*/
}
#div2
{
  box-shadow: 0 5px #888; /*shadow on bottom side*/
  /*here Why shadow to bottom instead of right-left*/
  /*here structure isn't same as padding order t-r-b-l ?*/
}
#div3
{
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #888; /*shadow on right side*/
}
#div4
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #888; /*shadow on all 4 sides*/
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="text1">text1</span>
<span class="text2">text2</span>
<span class="text3">text3</span>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
<div class="myDiv" id="div1"></div>
<div class="myDiv" id="div2"></div>
<div class="myDiv" id="div3"></div>
<div class="myDiv" id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply read the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow ... everything is details. Logically not all the properties will work the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you very much. I just got confused about it. But from the link you provided it's too much easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `box-shadow` properties differ from paddings/margins/borders, the order is the following:

1. Horizontal offset
2. Vertical offset
3. Blur radius
4. Spread radius

And when you, for example, do the following:

```
#div3 {
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #888; /*shadow on right side*/
}
```

Actually, you just move the shadow to the right. Take a look at this table, properties are described pretty well here:

[image]

And the reference for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp.